# Change mapping in the session

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a Informatica session which is linked to a wrong mapping.
How do i change the mapping from M1 to M2 in the same session S1 and Workflow W1 WITHOUT importing/exporting as XML and making the changes ???

Answer (score 6):

Invalidate the current mapping temporarily and refresh the session. This would allow you to choose a different mapping for your session. Pick the new one.

Don't forget to validate your old mapping.

Source: [ITTOOLBOX](http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/informatica-l/how-to-change-a-used-mapping-in-a-session-to-a-different-mapping-1727612)

Comment: I found this to be the best method, and the fastest, safest/least intrusive way to invalidate a mapping to be deleting all links to the source qualifier.

Comment: THANK YOU! I wouldn't ahve thought to to do this, and would have reverted to the xml export or creating the session brand new.

Answer (score 2):

XML import/export is the only "official" way to do this. If you don't want to do that, you will have to create a new session S2 and attach the mapping M2 to that session.

**One possible extra option, with disclaimer:** If you have access to Informatica's Oracle database (that holds the metadata), you could perhaps make this change directly there. But you would *really* have to know what you're doing, or else you are likely to mess things up pretty badly. This is certainly not the recommended way of making changes!

Answer (score 1):

The informatica metadata tables confuses you , dont change at that level. All the way is invalidate the mapping by removing port or by syntax errors. Workflw asks you new mapping. This is the best way apart all.  Informatica should add new feature to allow us to do this.

Answer (score 0):

XML export is one of the best way.
Export the session object and then edit the xml file where you need to change the mapping name. Now when you'd import it, it'll ask for the mapping to associate with.
This way you can do it.